# In c#, Is it possible to loop through multiple collections of the same base type?

Tags: c#, collections, .net-2.0

Suppose classes 'Apple', 'Banana' and 'Orange' all inherit from 'Fruit'.

Now suppose we have member variable lists -

```
List<Apple> mApples; 

List<Banana> mBananas; 

List<Orange> mOranges;
```

Can we form a loop that does something equivalent to the following?

```
foreach( Fruit fruit in mApples, mBananas, mOranges )  
{   
   fruit.Slice();   
}
```

I'm using .net 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.AddRange( mApples );
list.AddRange( mBananas );
list.AddRange( mOranges );

foreach( Fruit item in list )
{
    item.Slice();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would have to concatenate the lists

```
foreach(Fruit fruit in mApples.Cast<Fruit>()
        .Concat(mBananas.Cast<Fruit>())
        .Concat(mOranges.Cast<Fruit>()))
{
    fruit.Slice();
}
```

**Edit**

This would be a possible 2.0 solution

```
    foreach(Fruit fruit in Concat<Fruit>(mApples, mBananas, mOranges))
    {
        fruit.Slice();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] arr)
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable col in arr)
        foreach (T item in col)
            yield return item;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think 'Cast' is available in .net 2.0 (should have made that clear). That does seem like a nice trick though.

Comment: @Blake Neither is Concat im afraid.

Comment: @John Was not clear that it needed to be 2.0 in the question at the time.

Comment: @John 1.1 was not a requirement